# Typescript type definition works, but error shown on type definition

Tags: typescript

```ts
const someObject = {
  topLevelKey1: {
    midLevelKeyA: {
      someProp: ['a', 'b'],
    },
  },
  topLevelKey2: {
    midLevelKeyB: {
      someProp: ['c', 'd', 'e'],
    },
    midLevelKeyC: {
      someProp: ['g'],
    },
  },
} as const;
```

I wanted to define a function that basically looked like `someFunction(topLevelKey, midLevelKey, objectWithKeysmatchingToProp2)`, so a valid call would for example be `someFuntion('topLevelKey2', 'midLevelKeyB', {c: 2, d: 3, e: 4})`.

I am struggling with the typing of the third argument. For simplicity's sake I am writing my current code below as a simple type (rather than a generic function)

```ts
type X<
    T extends keyof typeof someObject,
    K extends keyof (typeof someObject)[T]
> = {
        [key in (typeof someObject)[T][K]['someProp'][number]]: number;
    };
const a: X<'topLevelKey2', 'midLevelKeyC'> = {
    f: 3
};
```

The bizarre thing is that that type *completely seems to work* (I get autocomplete for the keys of the object, I get errors if the object keys are incorrect, etc.), however typescript shows an error on the `(typeof someObject)[T][K]['someProp'][number]` part:

> Type '"someProp"' cannot be used to index type '{ readonly topLevelKey1: { readonly midLevelKeyA: { readonly prop1: readonly []; readonly someProp: readonly ["a", "b"]; }; }; readonly topLevelKey2: { readonly midLevelKeyB: { readonly prop1: readonly []; readonly someProp: readonly ["c", "d", "e"]; }; readonly midLevelKeyC: { ...; }; }; }[T][K]'.
> Type '{ readonly topLevelKey1: { readonly midLevelKeyA: { readonly prop1: readonly []; readonly someProp: readonly ["a", "b"]; }; }; readonly topLevelKey2: { readonly midLevelKeyB: { readonly prop1: readonly []; readonly someProp: readonly ["c", "d", "e"]; }; readonly midLevelKeyC: { ...; }; }; }[T][K]["someProp"][number]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
>
> Type '{ readonly topLevelKey1: { readonly midLevelKeyA: { readonly prop1: readonly []; readonly someProp: readonly ["a", "b"]; }; }; readonly topLevelKey2: { readonly midLevelKeyB: { readonly prop1: readonly []; readonly someProp: readonly ["c", "d", "e"]; }; readonly midLevelKeyC: { ...; }; }; }[T][keyof { ...; }[T]]["so...' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
> Type '{ readonly topLevelKey1: { readonly midLevelKeyA: { readonly prop1: readonly []; readonly someProp: readonly ["a", "b"]; }; }; readonly topLevelKey2: { readonly midLevelKeyB: { readonly prop1: readonly []; readonly someProp: readonly ["c", "d", "e"]; }; readonly midLevelKeyC: { ...; }; }; }[T][string]["someProp"][nu...' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
>
>     Type '{ readonly topLevelKey1: { readonly midLevelKeyA: { readonly prop1: readonly []; readonly someProp: readonly ["a", "b"]; }; }; readonly topLevelKey2: { readonly midLevelKeyB: { readonly prop1: readonly []; readonly someProp: readonly ["c", "d", "e"]; }; readonly midLevelKeyC: { ...; }; }; }[T][string]["someProp"][nu...' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
>
> Type 'number' cannot be used to index type '{ readonly topLevelKey1: { readonly midLevelKeyA: { readonly prop1: readonly []; readonly someProp: readonly ["a", "b"]; }; }; readonly topLevelKey2: { readonly midLevelKeyB: { readonly prop1: readonly []; readonly someProp: readonly ["c", "d", "e"]; }; readonly midLevelKeyC: { ...; }; }; }[T][K]["someProp"]'.

Basically if I put a `@ts-ignore` in front of that line I get all the type safety that I seem to desire... but that hardly seems to be a good idea. Anybody any idea what's going on here?

Here is a link to the [typescript playground with the aforementioned code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmB5ARgKycWBeGA3gLABQM5MUIADgDJIBuSANgNJICeAjAFyGkVBMBAEsAJvSZtOAQT7EyQpdQBONXjADaAXQA0ApUPjIACmup9NAcgCGV3TCtoreg0oC++xeU9vKNSRZ2DgAmeT9BUQlGIM4AIXDvQ3JVdUtXJOTjJDMaSytge0cxIqskFy9k30yKKMDpDgBhROTBVOoNHUrW8mzciy0rADNSgHMXCIp3P2r3GBsIGFBIKABuUlIoDmokGAANAB4-ABUYJAAPKCQwMUWAa04QIcptpCe4RFRMbChu8lYzpdrrcYA8OO8ABRbHbvbLoLA4ACUmmO2lIAD4YPgFMlNGCYCIwDAoa9YZ94T9kajNKxtNY+uYXJowABXBBoJAqbTaPis9mc9ZJdyC5bQeZ8Q5WKh0GINEKlOqy4KNKyY7F+UZ8ADMfxgQ21pGFQA) showing the error. Also worth noting that when I remove the `midLevel` part (`K`) then [everything works fine](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmB5ARgKycWBeGA3gLABQM5MUIADgDJIBuSANgNJICeAjAFyGkVBMagCcavGAG0AugBoBQ8vGQAFMdT6SA5AEMtsmFrRa5C8gF95ZClTqMW7DgCY%20xa4tHjNp90OVI1Gk0tYH1DABMwrSQTK0FLUnMYHQgYUEgoAG5SUigOaiQYAA0AHjMYABUYJAAPKCQwcNSAa04QADNKfKQOuERUTGwoUgA%20GHw3RXJJVo4YAEswGAAKPILe-3QsHABKSQrpbX9A6hNJMABXBDQkEWlpPkvr2%20zfc1f06GS%20Uq1beiYbE4Ti0Ywm5QA5nwAMxxCjtGGJTJAA).

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing the code to make it easier to see what's happening here, such as [this version](https://tsplay.dev/NDAOlm).  Keylike type parameters conventionally have names like `K` or `P`, and you're using `key` and `T` for two of those.  Also giving `typeof someObject` a type name helps (at least for me).

Comment: It's a known bug (so longstanding that it's probably just a design limitation at this point); see [ms/TS#21760](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760) and the linked questions/answers.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for closing as dupe! My bad for failing to find them myself, but thanks  . (As for naming of type parameters: I really should start using longer more descriptive names for those, so thanks for pointing that out )